# How do I switch the object of my database "MySQL" between two actions?

Tags: mysql, chatbot, rasa, rasa-nlu

I am creating my own chatbot that can interface with my internal database, and I want to avoid creating a database connection every time I call an action, instead I would like to pass the MySQL connection object as a parameter.
`class ConnectToDatabase(Action):

```
def name(self):
    return "action_connect_to_database"

def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
           "Parameters of my db"
        )
        conn_json = json.dumps(conn, default=str)
        return [SlotSet("database_connection", conn_json)]
    except Exception as e:
         dispatcher.utter_message(text=f"Error: {str(e)}")
```

class ExecuteDatabaseQuery(Action):

```
def name(self):
    return "action_execute_database_query"

def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
    try:
        conn = (tracker.get_slot("database_connection"))
        conn = json.loads(conn)
        print("Conn3:", str(type(conn)))
        ...`
```

But this gives me an error, specifically in the ExecuteDatabaseQuery function the "conn" object turns out to be empty, so the way "database_connection" is passed into the slot is wrong.
Can anyone tell me why this is the case?

I have been trying to pass an object, specifically the database connection, between two python actions in the RASA Framework with the goal of optimizing resources.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why the "conn" object is empty in the `ExecuteDatabaseQuery` function is because the `json.loads()` function is trying to load a string, but the "database_connection" slot is actually a JSON object.

To fix this, you need to change the way that you are serializing and deserializing the database connection object. Instead of using `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()`, you can use the `rasa.shared.utils.io.json_to_dict()` and `rasa.shared.utils.io.dict_to_json()` functions.

Here is the updated code for the `ConnectToDatabase` action:

```
class ConnectToDatabase(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "action_connect_to_database"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        try:
            conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                "Parameters of my db"
            )
            return [SlotSet("database_connection", rasa.shared.utils.io.dict_to_json(conn))]
        except Exception as e:
            dispatcher.utter_message(text=f"Error: {str(e)}")
```

And here is the updated code for the ExecuteDatabaseQuery action:

```
class ExecuteDatabaseQuery(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "action_execute_database_query"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        try:
            conn = rasa.shared.utils.io.json_to_dict(tracker.get_slot("database_connection"))
            print("Conn3:", str(type(conn)))
            ...
        except Exception as e:
            dispatcher.utter_message(text=f"Error: {str(e)}")
```

With this change, the "conn" object will now be properly serialized and deserialized, and it will not be empty in the `ExecuteDatabaseQuery` function.

Comment: I get an error: 
"Error: module 'rasa.shared.utils.io' has no attribute 'dict_to_json'
Error: module 'rasa.shared.utils.io' has no attribute 'json_to_dict'"